# Why is TypeORM returning no records in this simple query?

Tags: typeorm

I'm trying to get all the users on my system that match a *complex* where conditional with TypeORM. My end query would look something like this:

```
connection.createQueryBuilder()
  .select().from(User, "user")
  .where("email IS NULL OR email NOT LIKE '%@example.com'")
  .getMany()
```

If I run that query with `getCount()` it works and tells me how many I have, but `getMany()` return `[]`

In fact, I simplified it to this:

```
console.log(
  await connection.createQueryBuilder()
    .select().from(User, "user")
    .getManyAndCount())
```

I get this surprising result (with logging enabled):

```
query: SELECT * FROM "user" "user"
query: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT("user"."id")) as "cnt" FROM "user" "user"
[ [], 14 ]
```

Any ideas why I would get no users when the count shows 14? I run the query manually and it obviously shows the users... what's going on here?

The code that Carlo offered in one of the answers:

```
await connection.getRepository(User).findAndCount()
```

works, but that won't let me have my `where` clause (as far as I know, I'm still new to TypeORM). I'm just sharing this to show that the User model seems to be working fine, except when I use it with the query builder to select a bunch of users (counting and deleting works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your code syntax as simple as possible since TypeORM docs (now) are't perfect.

Try using **[Find Options](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options)** since I can't find any *getManyAndCount()* method for QueryBuilder:

```js
const users = await connection
                     .getRepository(User)
                     .findAndCount();
```

EDIT:

Of course you can have (complex) where clause with find.
You can chain multiple *where* clauses (OR) with a really simple syntax. Check out all options [here](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options/advanced-options).

Example that map your "raw" query:

```js
const users = await connection
                     .getRepository(User)
                     .findAndCount({
                       where: [
                         {
                           email: IsNull(),
                         },
                         {
                           email: Not(Like('%@example.com')),
                         },
                       ],
                     });
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I need to add a where clause that it's not possible with `findAndCount`, that's why I'm using the query builder, but I distilled to the absolute minimum that shows the query is just not working.

Comment: And just for the record, the code you shared, works.

Comment: I added some details to the question.

Comment: I'm still puzzled by why my code doesn't work... but yours does.

Answer (score 0):

Let me divide that step-by-step approach

1. despite of `getManyAndCount()` use `getRawEntities()`
2. you will get the data for sure by using 1st point
3. now concentrate on the keys you are getting on data
4. use the same key on your select query and done

if you didn't get records using `getRawEntities()`:

I. try to use select * i.e, `select()`

II. check the column name and correct that

Additionally, It can also depend on your entity structure. Carefully check that too.